# Given functions of the form: $n \bmod a = b$. How to calculate n?

Tags: number-theory

Given functions of the form:

$n \bmod a = b$

In general, What is the easiest way to calculate the minimum positive $n$?

For example:

$n \bmod 2 = 1$

$n \bmod 3 = 2$

$n \bmod 5 = 2$

The calculated n should equal $17$.

Comment: This is an application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem; most proofs of this theorem are constructive and provide a simple algorithm.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Finding_the_solution_with_basic_algebra_and_modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general one can employ the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) or [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22easy+crt%22). However, as is often true for small cases, this system of congruences admits a constant case optimization: here since $\rm\:n\equiv 2\:$ both mod $3$ and $5,\!\:$ we deduce $\rm\:n\equiv 2\pmod{15},\:$ so $\rm\:n\equiv 2\:$ or $\rm\:\!17\pmod{30},\:$ necessarily the latter, since $\rm\:n\:$ is odd by the first congruence.